# Two variables in a makefile target

Tags: c, makefile, embedded, gnu-make

I would like to specify a makefile target with more than one automatic variable but I do not know how to do it.

For example:

```
build/%_$(MPU).o: %.c
      ${MP_CC} $< -o $@ -c -mcpu=$(MPU) $(CFLAGS)
```

The idea here is to create many object files (one for each microcontroller architecture) from a single source file. For example, if my source file is BinarySearch.c I want to make

```
build/BinarySearch_33FJ128MC710A.o
build/BinarySearch_33FJ128MC706A.o
etc.
```

Sadly, I can only match on the source file name "BinarySearch" and cannot match on the MPU names. Perhaps another way to write my intention would be

```
 build/%1_%2.o: %1.c
      ${MP_CC} $< -o $@ -c -mcpu=%2 $(CFLAGS)
```

where %1 matches the source file name and %2 matches the MPU name. Of course the make syntax does not actually work like this; I am just trying to convey my desire.

It is likely I am taking the wrong approach here but I am not sure which make feature I should use to achieve this goal. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is something about this not working? Oh, the question is about getting it to match the source file?

Comment: Can you be more explicit in describing what _problem_ you are seeing using this approach?

Comment: ***[Look Here perhaps?](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/make/make_11.html)***

Comment: What I am trying to do is match both the MPU name with "$(MPU)" and the source file name with "%" which does not work. What I want is to be able to match two separate things in the target, the source file name (BinarySearch=% in this case) and some other thing (MPU=33FJ128MC710A as well). I do not know how to get the match on the second thing.

Answer (score 0):

What you have written is almost there. However, *make* cannot work out the CPU you are compiling for from the source filename. Just tell *make* the CPU you are after.

Makefile (as above):

```
build/%_$(MPU).o: %.c
    ${MP_CC} $< -o $@ -c -mcpu=$(MPU) $(CFLAGS)
```

Command-line:

```
$ make build/BinarySearch_33FJ128MC710A.o MPU=33FJ128MC710A
```

If mentioning *33FJ128MC710A* twice on the same command-line is too onerous for you, you can use secondary expansion to get the effect you are after. Note though that this only works on the pre-requisites, so you will need to re-work your pattern a bit.

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:

build/%.o: $$(firstword $$(subst _, ,$$*_)).c
    ${MP_CC} $< -o $@ -c -mcpu=$(lastword $(subst _, ,$*)) $(CFLAGS)
```

Now you just need

```
$ make build/BinarySearch_33FJ128MC710A.o
```

on the command-line (`$*` in the recipe matches whatever the `%` matched in the dependency line, which is quite often really convenient).